# Getting empty paths key in swagger when deployed. Local is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using `swagger-jsdoc`. Everything seems fine and I am getting the json till I am using `localhost`, when I use live url, it's giving me nothing in the paths keys ie.

```
{
    "info": {
        "title": "App API",
        "version":"0.0.0",
        "description":"Server API documentation"
    },
    "host":"something.com",
    "basePath":"/",
    "schemes":["https"],
    "swagger":"2.0",
    "paths":{},
    "definitions":{},
    "responses":{},
    "parameters":{},
    "securityDefinitions":{},
    "tags":[]
}
```

This is what I am getting on live. The same code is working on `localhost/swagger.json`, but not with `https://something.com/swagger.json`

```
var swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');

var swaggerOptions = {
    swaggerDefinition: config.swaggerDefinition || {
        info: { // API informations (required)
            title: 'Hello World', // Title (required)
            version: '1.0.0', // Version (required)
            description: 'A sample API', // Description (optional)
        },
        host: 'localhost:3000', // Host (optional)
        basePath: '/', // Base path (optional)
    },
    apis: ['./routes/*.js'], // Path to the API docs
};

var swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOptions);

router.get('/swagger.json', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(swaggerSpec);
});
```

Comment: Is it the case even if you add a `/etc/hosts` entry for localhost and try to access it using the new entry?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, local everything is fine but when going live getting bare skeleton json. Hope you have resolve this issue. If yes, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arose due to the path of the routes.

I was using `apis: [ './routes/*.js' ]`

But my server was having path `./bin/www` so in these cases `./routes` won't work at all, the best way while implementing this would be to use `__dirname` instead.
eg.

```
apis: [`${__dirname}/routes/*.js`]
```

I have solved it the same day but forgot to add an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem before. If you're using pm2, you might have the same issue as mine.

In my case, the issue was resolved when i changed the `paths` in `apis` from using

```
apis: [ './routes/*.js' ]
```

into

```
apis: [ __dirname + 'routes/*.js' ]
```

So using `__dirname` instead of `.`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be a problem with your host option in `config.swaggerDefinition`. Is it set to the correct domain?

Comment: This fits more as a comment rather than an answer.